# How do you write an Iterator for a CloseRanged of a generic type in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, generics

I am trying to write an Iterator for this generic class:

```
    class  Point<T>(val x: T, val y: T): Comparable<Point<T>> where T: Number, T: Comparable<T> {
        override fun compareTo(other: Point<T>): Int {
            return compareValuesBy(this, other, Point<T>::x, Point<T>::y
            )
        }
    }
```

I can create a range of Points: `val range = Point(1,1) .. Point(10.10)`. When I call `forEach` on `range`, it says something to the effect that I have to write an iterator. So here's what I've tried:

```
    operator fun ClosedRange<Point<T>>.iterator(): Iterator<Point<T>>{}
```

The error is 'unresolved reference T'. What should I do here?

**UPDATE:**

Now the working iterator function is this:

```
    operator fun <T> ClosedRange<Point<T>>.iterator(): Iterator<T>
                                where T: Number, T: Comparable<T>
```

I've hit another road block. I need to increase the Point so that the overriden `next` function can work. So I have this extension `inc` function:

```
    operator fun <T> Point<T>.inc(): Point<T> where T: Number, T: Comparable<T> {
        return this(x + 1, y +1)
    }
```

The problem is 'this(x + 1, y + 1) doesn't work because x and y are type T. How can you work around this?

Comment: should you define the value of `T` by then? if i'm misunderstanding, can you add more context?

Answer (score 0):

Your extension function is for a generic type, thus type parameters need to be declared:

```
class  Point<T>(val x: T, val y: T): Comparable<Point<T>> where T: Number, T: Comparable<T> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Point<T>): Int {
        return compareValuesBy(this, other, Point<T>::x, Point<T>::y
        )
    }
}

operator fun <T> ClosedRange<Point<T>>.iterator(): Iterator<Point<T>> where T : Number, T: Comparable<T> {
    ......
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a bunch. I've updated my question. Please help.

Comment: That's another question. `+` operator is not defined on `Number`. You need to find some appropriate method to call or some appropriate class to use.